# Crystal Report Error : The maximum report processing jobs limit configured

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

I am getting an error while opening the report:

```
The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached
```

I searched the internet and almost everyone is suggesting the solution:

```
ReportDocument.Close();
ReportDocument.Dispose();
```

I tried it already but still I am getting the same error almost everyday on the production server. My code is below:

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowReport();
}

protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
     if (rptDoc != null)
     {
         rptDoc.Close();
         rptDoc.Dispose();
     }

     base.OnUnload(e);
}

protected void ShowReport()
{
      rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/RptFiles/rptPrint.rpt"));
      //Rest of the code
}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you try logging something in the OnUnload method and see if its getting called or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

goto: Run > regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > SAP BUSINESS OBJECT .....

[image]

Comment: Change from 75 to -1